# How can i link my mesh

Tags: linked-data

I have icosphere subdivide and separated. I have duplicated one mesh and separated from the sphere. Selecting all the mesh and the separate mesh i press ctrl+L to link. But the result is the mesh rotate. I want edit the link mesh which is separate so that all the mesh with icosphere follow.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This will not work, since not all objects are the same. Most faces have 6 vertices, but some have only 5. And when linking all meshes, they are looking all the same way, because all single meshes have the same global orientation. Sure, each face has a distinct look-at vector, but global orientation is always the same.

What do you want to achive? As a suggestion, try using combined array modifiers.

Comment: @Grimm Yes there are 6 and 5 vertices if u want u can separate both separate and link but there is option to select all 6 or 5 vertices i.e Shift+G -> Area

Answer (score 1):

The closest I came to what you probably want is this:

[image]

First, you need a new master mesh, because yours is not aligned to one of the main axis. So, create a new one. I used a simple little plane.

Now, link all meshes as you did before. And also as before, all meshes will look at the same direction as your master mesh.

Next, add an empty at the center of your Icosphere. This will be the look-at point for all meshes. So add a *Track To* constraint to one of them, select your empty as target, and switch *To* to Z and *Up* to X.

Last, select all your meshes with the constrainted one as active, and *Object > Constraint > Conpy Constraints To Selected Objects*.